# Open external application from a app started as daemon

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I have a issue. I have a C++ application which is started by a script that start on boot. The device where this is happening is a small comptuer (raspberry pi style) without a graphic interface, only console access.

The problem comes when the c++ application runs other apps like sshpass, sftp or ssh, it throws error `/bin/sh application not found` (any of the applications mentioned before). But, if I kill the process and run it manually, everything works like charm. What am i missing?
The externall apps are on the same folder as the c++ application and are called like this `./application`

thanks

EDIT: Im using system() to call the app.
I have tried execv, execve and still can't make it work.

Comment: You need to specify how you're "running" the other apps -- the system() call?  Using fork() and exec()? posix_spawn()? CreateProcess()?  Some other call that depends on your unstated OS, runtime C library, and other unmentioned but very pertinent information?

Comment: I'm using system() to call the app

Comment: Did you check the CWD of the app?

Comment: On *nix systems, prefer [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)ing and calling [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) or one of its [front ends](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html)...

Comment: system() execs /bin/sh to run your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer to myself in case somebody comes here with the same issue.

My launcher script was calling my application with full path. What i did to fix it, I moved to the applications folder (cd /appPath/) and then launch the application normally (./application), that fixed my issue.